# Select item with .not()

Tags: jquery

I need to be able to select div element on hover but not the one that has span with class notMe.

```
<div class="myEm">
    <span class="lineItem"></span> em 1
</div>
<div class="myEm">
    <span class="lineItem notMe"></span> em 1
</div>
<div class="myEm">
    <span class="lineItem"></span> em 1
</div>
```

Can't seem to be able to figure out how to skip that one. Tried:

```
 $('.myEm').not('.notMe').hover(
        ...
 );
```

Do I need to use .each() and check for child with that class?

Comment: Try something like `$('.myEm span').not('.myEm span.notMe').hover(
        ...
 );`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will work:

```
$(".myEm:not(:has(.notMe))")
```

This excludes elements that contain a `.notMe`.

---

Docs:

- https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/
- https://api.jquery.com/has-selector/

Comment: A better method than my comment.

Answer (score 0):

You should probable use Mooseman's approach as it is shorted and simpler this is just an alternative way I could think of..

```
$('.myEm').hover(

if( $( this ).children( "span.notMe" ).length ){

       return false;

     } else {

      // do your stuff here...
  }
);
```